# mat-slide-toggle with 3 states

Tags: angular, angular-material, toggle, mat-slider

I am trying to build a mat-slide-toggle button with 3 states which look like something like this in my angular application.

[image]

Is there anything like this in the mat-slide-toggle to achieve this?

Comment: not able to see image

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WCyu.png Its something like this

Comment: seems it's doable... you need to override the styles of material classes based on your condition

Comment: Any examples or references would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so based on the state we need to override material styles. look below to see what you need to override.

[click here to see stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nnplnv?file=src/app/slide-toggle-configurable-example.html)->`style.scss` file have the overrided styles

```
//slide styles
#one {
  //1st state
  .mat-slide-toggle-thumb-container {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0) !important;
  }
  .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
    background-color: red !important;
  }
  .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
    background-color: rgb(219, 123, 123) !important;
  }
}
#two {
  //2nd state
  .mat-slide-toggle-thumb-container {
    transform: translate3d(27px, 0, 0) !important;
  }
  .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
    background-color: blue !important;
  }
  .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
    background-color: rgb(166, 162, 238) !important;
  }
}
#three {
  //3rd state
  .mat-slide-toggle-thumb-container {
    transform: translate3d(56px, 0, 0) !important;
  }
  .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
    background-color: green !important;
  }
  .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
    background-color: rgb(93, 197, 102) !important;
  }
}
.mat-slide-toggle-bar {
  //slide width
  width: 75px !important;
}
```

it's your responsibility to change the state in the typescript file based on your logic.

```
<mat-card class="result">
  <mat-card-content>
    <h2 class="example-h2">Result</h2>

    <section class="example-section" [id]="mystatus">
      <mat-slide-toggle class="example-margin" (click)="change()">
        Slide me!- now i'm {{mystatus}} state
      </mat-slide-toggle>
    </section>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```